# IBM MQ Put Method - Why use MQPutMessageOptions?

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I'm using the standalone component amqmdnet.dll.

The put method has 2 methods:

```
Put(MqMessage message)
Put(MqMessage message, MQPutMessageOptions options)
```

Why/when would I use the options?  The documentation is not clear on this.  What advantages does the options parameter give me?  Most of the code sample seem to new up an options parameter.

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111250_.htm#q111250___p

Comment: You would use them if you need any of the features that various MQPMO_ options give you such as putting one or more messages in a unit of work with MQPMO_SYNCPOINT or passing context information like MQMD.UserID or MQMD.ApplIdentityData using MQPMO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT.

Comment: @JoshMc - Why would I need to pass context information, most of the times we are just placing JSON data on a queue.  Sorry I need to understand a use case.  I understand the sync point case.

Comment: @JonRaynor it was an example - most applications should never have a need for MQPMO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT.

Comment: The strange thing with this construction is that it seemingly allows conflicting options to be set. Like `MQPMO_SYNCPOINT` and `MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT` which both have a different internal ID (2 and 4) which allows very strange setups. Or am I missing the point here?